# Character advancement - buying new skills with Karma

Tags: skills, shadowrun-sr5

p.105 Core Rule book

> The skill table works on a similar principle, though Active Skill
>   ratings costs are computed at new Rating x 2. If you are purchasing a
>   brand new skill, find the desired rating on the table and pay that
>   cumulative amount. For example, if you are purchasing the running
>   skill for the first time, and are buying it up to Rating 3, you will
>   pay 12 Karma.

It says cumulative for a Rank 3. To me that says Add up Rank 1 + Rank 2 + Rank 3 and cumulative reach the Sum of those values. Rank 1 is 2 Karma, Rank 2 is 6 Karma, Rank 3 is 12 Karma. To me that is cumulative 2+6+12 = 20 Karma.

I can't find somewhere in the errata that covers this.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following the rule you quote, first you calculate "new Rating x 2":

- Rank 1 x 2 = **2** karma
- Rank 2 x 2 = **4** karma
- Rank 3 x 2 = **6** karma

To buy a brand new skill, this is *cumulative*, so for rank 3 from scratch: **2 + 4 + 6 = 12** karma total cost.

Your error was to take the *cumulative rank rating*, times by two, and add each result cumulatively. So for rank 2 you are calculating (1 + 2) x 2 instead of just 2 x 2, and for rank 3 you are calcuating (1 + 2 + 3) x 2 instead of just 3 x 2.